# ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that makes use of `Animated` component from react native. I started writing a test case to simulate `onPress` of a component, which calls a function that has `Animated.timing` in it, and `setState`.

running `jest` works fine, but the tests never stops running, and one unrelated test case that I've written before never seem to pass now (which passed before).

running `jest --watch`, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at Function.bezier (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:113:21)
      at ease (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:34:24)
      at TimingAnimation._easing (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:133:18)
      at TimingAnimation.onUpdate (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/animations/TimingAnimation.js:107:45)

 RUNS  src/__tests__/SlideDownMenu.test.js

/home/nrion/Desktop/mobile-ui/PriceInsight_app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:114
      return _bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2);
             ^
TypeError: _bezier is not a function
    at Function.bezier (/home/nrion/Desktop/mobile-ui/PriceInsight_app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:224:12)
    at ease (/home/nrion/Desktop/mobile-ui/PriceInsight_app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:94:21)
    at TimingAnimation._easing (/home/nrion/Desktop/mobile-ui/PriceInsight_app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:255:16)
    at TimingAnimation.onUpdate (/home/nrion/Desktop/mobile-ui/PriceInsight_app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/animations/TimingAnimation.js:138:14)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

### Link to repl

https://repl.it/repls/PartialGrimyMetadata

### Environment:

- OS: Linux 4.14
- Node: 6.14.2
- Yarn: 1.7.0
- npm: 3.10.10
- Watchman: Not Found
- Xcode: N/A
- Android Studio: Not Found

Answer (score 181, accepted):

OK, found a solution.

Should use `jest.useFakeTimers()`

Note: Put the code above just after `import` section in your test file.

Comment: where do we use this?

Comment: @dopatraman I used it in my test file after the imports. (Is that correct? It worked.) But see below from TARJU also about its use.

Comment: if u have a src\__tests__\jestSetup.ts better to set it there, it will work for every test.

Comment: unfornately didn't work for me, i used websocket conennection in a tested file which keeps failing

Comment: See the documentation here: https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks

Comment: √ renders correctly (400 ms)

  console.warn
    Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing. Falling back to JS-based animation. To resolve this, add `RCTAnimation` module to this app, or remove `useNativeDriver`. Make sure to run `bundle exec pod install` first. Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md

Answer (score 61):

### jest.useFakeTimers()

With above it's extremely important to understand this

jest.useFakeTimers() mocks out setTimeout and other timer functions with mock functions.

If running multiple tests inside of one file or describe block, jest.useFakeTimers(); can be called before each test manually or with a setup function such as beforeEach.

### Not doing so will result in the internal usage counter not being reset.

Answer (score 38):

I would like to contribute to the answer.

Well let's see the error message

`ReferenceError: You are trying to 'import' a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.`

Torn down means: Jest already finished running and some part of your code is trying to execute after jest has already finished running the test. This is pretty common on Javascript due to its asynchronous nature.

Sometimes it happens after a promise callback was executed. For example:

```
import { someProcess } from 'a-library'

task.job().then(result => {
    someProcess(result)
})
```

In the example above, the code imports `someProcess` from `a-library`.

If the method `job` from the `task` object takes longer than the jest execution, its callback (`then()` invocation) will run outside jest because jest has already finished running the test. Therefore when `someProcess` gets executed it will be loaded from `a-library` so jest will complain that you are trying to load a library after jest has been torn down.

The answer marked as the solution is partially right because calling `jest.useFakeTimers()` will prevent your code to wait the `n` seconds you supposed to wait when calling `setTime` or similar, making your code artificially synchronous.

Making your test `await` those method calls would help you understand better where the error is being introduced.

The code that worked for me was

```
describe("Some test set", () => {
  let heavyWorkingService = library.workingService();

   // We are marking the test function call as async
   test(("Name of the test"), async  () => {

     // we are awaiting heavyWorkingService to finish its job
     await heavyWorkingService("some data")
   })
})
```

In my real scenario, my code was getting data from firebase and because I'm not using mocks for this test, it was trying to import firebase after the `.get()` data read returned. Marking the test as `async` and calling the method with the `await` keyword solved my problem

Of course there are a lot of ways to deal with this error, just wanted you to know the true reason behind this error so you can work in the right solution for your tests!

Answer (score 34):

Add `"testEnvironment": "jsdom"` into `jest` key in package.json or jest.config.js

```json
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "preset": "react-native",
   ...
```

taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64567257/728287

Comment: in addition to that, I have added `afterEach(cleanup);` and the warning went away. :D

Comment: @Ponja afterEach is undefined in my case, any idea from where to import it ?

Comment: it's part of jest https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown

Comment: Why does this work? There is no DOM in react native environment, so this should not be needed.

Comment: @PetrHurtak maybe you're right. the most important thing looks like it's the `preset` https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html

Comment: If someone has a `React Native for Web` project, this solution works.

Answer (score 25):

I am using `@testing-library/react-native`, so what I did is to `cleanup` in the setup file.

```js
// jest.setup.js
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react-native';

afterEach(cleanup);
```

Comment: ReferenceError: afterEach is not defined

Comment: You need to use setupFilesAfterEnv for beforeAll, afterAll, afterEach, etc

Answer (score 8):

None of above works for me. My solution is to add to **jest-setup.js** file this code:

```js
import { Animated } from 'react-native';

Animated.timing = () => ({
    start: () => jest.fn(),
});
```

Don't forget to include this file to your **package.json** jest configuration:

```json
...
  "jest": {
    ...,
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/src/tests/jest-setup.js"
    ]
  },
...
```

I hope it will help anybody

Comment: `Cannot assign to 'timing' because it is a read-only property.`

Answer (score 7):

add the below lines at the *very end* of the jest test file,
after all, tests are written.

```
afterAll(() => { 
  mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

**and also just ***run a single test*** file at a time**, for example,

`> jest --verbose --runInBand -- filename.test.js`

Comment: Thanks, adding the `--runInBand` parameter solved this for me.

Comment: @Stan you are welcome, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This solution doesn't solve. I am still having issue.

Comment: You might want to try `jest --detectOpenHandles --runInBand`

Answer (score 5):

`jest.useFakeTimers` was not an option for me since it brakes the execution of other libraries I am using.

My workaround was to simply add a delay after each test, so that any async operation has time to complete before Jest environment is torn down:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

describe('Test suite', () => {
  
  // Give time to any async operation to complete after each test
  afterEach(async () => {
    await sleep(2000);
  });

  // Also close any pending connection (or related) if any
  afterAll(async () => {
    await closeConnections();
  });

  it('My test', async () => {
    // Test...
  });
});
```

Of course the delay time must be tuned for your application.

Answer (score 4):

Add this into your jest.config.js

```js
 timers: "fake",
```

This helps me to resolve this problem.

My jest.config.js file now looks this way

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: "react-native",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|react-native-vector-icons)/)",
  ],
  timers: "fake",
};
```

In the latest versions of Jest use this one

```js
import type { Config } from "jest";

const config: Config = {
  preset: "react-native",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/template",
    "Libraries/Renderer",
    "RNTester/e2e",
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|react-native-vector-icons)/)",
  ],
  fakeTimers: {
    enableGlobally: true,
  },
  verbose: true,
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue while testing Apollo with `react-native-testing-library`.

In this case there were two queries, in a parent and child component. The parent query needed to resolve before the child rendered and fired its query.

The solution was to run the `wait()` function twice rather than just once. I assume the double-fire is necessary to ensure both queries run. The error message is very opaque though.

```
test("...", () => {
  const rr = render(...);
  await wait();
  await wait(); // Child query must also run
  expect(...);
}

// Wait a tick so the query runs
// https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-final-state
export async function wait(ms = 0) {
  await act(async () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `@testing-library/react-native`. On my test case, I need to call `render(<MyComponent/>)` twice so I needed to add `afterEach(cleanup)` that way it fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was using typeorm and put that code inside my jest.setup.ts

```
afterAll(async () => {
 const connection = getConnection();

 connection.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my bit to the discussion... Double-check if you have *any* asynchronous code in your test case.

My case was basically a lack of attention, see:

```
it('should not allow click', async () => {
    const page = await newE2EPage();
    await page.setContent(`<my-button disabled></my-button>`);

    const component = await page.find('my-button');

    // WRONG ! ! ! (since click() is async)
    component.click();

    // ✅ Correct
    await component.click()

    ...
  });
```

The error message isn't that straightforward to understand (at least it wasn't for me). I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

For me worked:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers({
    legacyFakeTimers: true,
  });
});

afterAll(() => {
  jest.useRealTimers();
});
```

Comment: you save my day, HERO! <3

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding `jest.useFakeTimers()` inside my `beforeEach()` method but it didn't resolve the issue for me.

This `jest.mock()` call above my test cases was the culprit for me:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    post: () => Promise.resolve({ data: 'data' }),
}));
```

Removing it resolved my issue.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "testEnvironment": "jsdom" in package.json didn't helped in my case.
Then I added in the test file under all imports:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
```

and inside describe but above the first test:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
```

and that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

**IN THIS CASE THE ERROR IS SELF EXPLANATORY:**

Maybe a bit late to the party but I just want to help whoever is still struggling with this. As the error says, the problem is that some part of your code is trying to `import` a module after the test has finished. Check the following code:

```js
it('should do something', () => {
   someAsyncFuntion(); // We arent awaiting this function so the test ends before execution
});

const someAsyncFunction = async () => {
  const {getByPlaceholderText} = render(<SomeComponent />)

  getByPlaceholderText('Some placeholder text')
}
```

With this code the error will be fired, but `why`? If we check the code for `getByPlaceholderText` we will see that it is dynamically importing the `TextInput` component:

```js
const getTextInputNodeByPlaceholderText = (node, placeholder, options = {}) => {
  try {
    const {
      TextInput
    } = require('react-native'); // <--- Here we have our import

    const {
      exact,
      normalizer
    } = options;
    return (0, _filterNodeByType.filterNodeByType)(node, TextInput) && (0, _matches.matches)(placeholder, node.props.placeholder, normalizer, exact);
  } catch (error) {
    throw (0, _errors.createLibraryNotSupportedError)(error);
  }
};
```

So as the error says, we are trying to import a module `after` the test has finished.

Comment: This explains why, but does not explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My project is with **ReactNative** and **TypeScipt**

and my Jest config by default is in **package.json**.

To solve this issue i just had to add **"timers": "fake"**

```
"jest": {
"timers": "fake",
"preset": "react-native",
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "ts",
  "tsx",
  "js",
  "jsx",
  "json",
  "node"
]}
```

The reason why you need this was already explained:

> Torn down means: Jest already finished running and some part of your code is trying to execute after jest has already finished running the test. This is pretty common on Javascript due to its asynchronous nature.

There's NO need to add "testEnvironment": "jsdom". As people say above; has no sense with ReactNative.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jest.useFakeTimers()` on top of code after imports, did not work for me.

I found the below solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6434#issuecomment-666056825)
now at least, I do not see the error now but a warning message appeared at the end saying..

`A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown.  Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.`

```
it('your test case', () => {...})

becomes:

it('your test case', async () => {...})
```

adding async removes the erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

**This is for NestJS developers.**

I found this while I was testing, turns out I just needed to import some modules, you need to know that the Test module and the real module have to be in 1:1. I mean Daaaaa. Silly, but sometimes you can get clumsy when it's mostly a repeatable job.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was that I was starting a server that never finishes (**open handle**) i.e apollo graphql server. It is not the best practice to do this but what worked for me is wrapping the start of a server in a try catch. For example

```
async function startServers() {

    try {
        await createExpressApp()
        await RunHttpsServer();
        await startApollo();
        await onStartNeo();
        await startWeaviate();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
}
```

tbh this is not the best way but if you know another please let me know as this gives the error

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

'This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my case here. I was working with unit tests and came across this error as winston logs related code was running after jest exited. So I mocked it as below and error was resolved.

```js
jest.mock("path_to_logs", () => ({
    logger: {
        debug: jest.fn(),
    },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I just wanted to let people know this answer who find it in a search.

The problem with the "ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down." is because the jest environment is already finished running but there is still unresolved Promises out there which will run after jest is done. That means that as the promise resolves, it tries to call expect() and other jest things when jest is no longer available.

The [currently] top answer works around this by converting everything to synchronous so you don't have to deal with it, but you don't need to do that. In Juan's answer, he made sure that his code waits before returning so that there are no outstanding promises.

But there is another way -- just need to return the promise from your test, and now jest has a handle on that promise and can wait for it to complete before continuing with other tests. This way, when your "then()" runs, it will not be after the rest of jest is done.

To re-use Juan's example above:

```js
describe("Some test set", () => {
  let heavyWorkingService = library.workingService();

   // We are marking the test function call as async
   test(("Name of the test"), async  () => {

     // jest will wait on heavyWorkingService to finish its job
     return heavyWorkingService("some data");
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I used `jest.useFakeTimers`() in `beforeEach`() method inside test suit of that file

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });
```

OR

use `jest.useFakeTimers()` on top of code after imports