# Supertest: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down

Tags: node.js, supertest

I'm using supertest to test api route in a node/typescript application. The server crashes with this error:

> ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

Here is the test:

```js
import request from "supertest";
import { server } from "../index";

describe("GET /user/:id", () => {
  it("return user information", (done) => {
    request(server)
      .get("/user/123")
      .set("Cookie", ["_id=567;locale=en"])
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

The jest config (which has a linter error: `'module' is not defined.`)

```js
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)",
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
  },
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you try mocking the imports you have on "server''?

Comment: Hi, no I just tested the endpoint with postman. Supertest didn't work for me.

Comment: See if it solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50793993/9973388. Is solved mine.